# PayPal IPN Variable Issue

Tags: php, html, paypal-ipn

PayPal IPN is a wonderful tool, and it has been working quite well for me - well, it's working let's just leave it at that for now). Now, I would like to gather quite a bit of information about my customer - information that is no supported by the built in PayPal IPN variables. I know that PayPal allows me to add two text fields two my custom button, and I see that there is a "custom" field which has been working quite well actually, but unfortunately, three fields won't cut it.

I need to have around 5 - 10 text fields where the user can input "custom" information, and I need to somehow have that sent back to my server with the IPN response. As I said, the custom field has been working great for me but I need some way to append the values of each text field into the custom variable prior to sending it in PayPal's direction. Is there some way to append the values of multiple text fields to that of a hidden field in a Form before the form gets sent out?

Here is an example HTML Form that I might be using:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="lkLKS3l2m"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">

<input type="text" value="Hardware ID" name="option_selection1"/>
<input type="text" value="Username" name="option_selection2"/>
<input type="password" value="Password" name="option_selection3"/>
<input type="text" value="notes1" name="option_selection4"/>
<input type="text" value="Notes2" name="option_selection5"/>
<input type="text" value="TEST1" name="option_selection7"/>
<input type="hidden" value= ( all of the text fields combined, separated by delimiter). name ="custom" />

</Form
```

So, might anyone have any solution to my small issue here?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a hosted button.

Comment: Then what would be the best way of going about doing this?

Comment: Use a non-hosted button, with all of the parameters in the form.  (and beware of the security issues)  Also, don't send passwords in web forms.

Comment: IPN will work with a non-hosted button? I honestly thought that was the entire purpose. Also, I'll look into your password suggestion, but nearly every website I've ever registered for has required me to input a password. What do you mean by not sending 'passwords in web forms' ?

Comment: Yes; IPN will work with a non-hosted button (a hosted button means a form with the `hosted_button_id` parameter).  I'm using it right now.

Comment: I mean don't send passwords _back_ – don't send a page to the browser that contains a plain-text password in a hidden field.

Comment: Sure you can do this. Use javascript/jQuery to combine the text field values on form submit and then update the hidden custom field.

Comment: Jesus, that was simple. If you could somehow give me an example, I'd accept that right away.

Comment: If you need to gather information for your own site, split the operations, by using one form to gather all the personal info. If that info is valid, tag it with an id. Then present another form with just the minimum info required for PayPal (amount, currency, etc, and that id in `custom`). When IPN returns, use the id in `custom` to identify the customer and do whatever is required for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to add each of the element's data to an array, then serialize it into the "custom" hidden field before it gets sent out to PayPal.

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing. Well here are your points.

Answer (score 0):

As an undocumented feature, PayPal lets you add more than just two text fields. The button generator creates a form with text fields nested in table cells like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Child's name">Child's name</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200">
```

You may add more of those increasing the elements' name pairs, ie on2, on3, on4 and os2, os3, os4 etc. Other fields like check boxes or textareas are possible, too, cf
[paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside)

It's not mentioned however, that all are restricted to a maxlength of 200. Increasing maxlength values in the form doesn't help, transmitted values get truncated at 200.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer as it is plain HTML, without needing javascript. Just have to remember that the HTML variables `on0` and `os0` et al are returned as `option_name1` and `option_selection1` et al by PDT/IPN. (left hand - right hand in the development team there!!) Also, there can be up to 7 for normal buttons.